# Можно ли с помощью Date.now() получить генератор настоящих случайных чисел?

Tags: javascript

Я измеряю время в случайный момент, наступающий в зависимости от действий пользователя (вот кто источник хаоса), а после беру последние миллисекунды. Собственно вопрос скорее заключается в том, настоящие ли это миллисекунды или браузер их как то оптимизирует?

Comment: вы хотите получить генератор случайных чисел или что?

Comment: Да, генератор настоящих случайных чисел.

Comment: Math.random() не подходит ?

Comment: Гугль по запросу "jscript date.now accuracy" даёт достаточно ссылок. Посмотрите, например, http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/ - товарищ утверждает, что дискретность там порядка 15 мс, да ещё и зависит от браузера и ОС. Впрочем, если брать именно последние пару цифр, думаю, там распределение будет достаточно равномерным. А вот если нужно несколько случайных чисел, то промежуток времени между их получением должен быть достаточно большим, чтобы не получить фэйк.

Comment: настоящие случайные числа вы так не получите.

Comment: Почему это не получу?

Comment: @Khipster потому что эти числа будут являться псевдослучайными?

Comment: Сфигали псевдослучайными?!